# Flutter - Validator is not responding with the name is required text and the screen is not moving to next screen after the press

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, requiredfieldvalidator

The validator is not showing the error message while I try to click the button without entering anything in the box and even after filling the box the bottom doesn't take me to the next screen.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Feedback Form"),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Center(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 40),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (String value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Name is required";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Enter your Name'),
              ),
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Next"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    return;
                  }
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                  );
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

}
}

Comment: you forget the widget Form .....

Comment: Where should I use the widget form?

Comment: i update my answer

Comment: Can you help me with this one please:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377932/the-method-data-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object-object-is-from-dar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you forget the Form widget

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Feedback Form"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
          child: Form( // add this
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction, // this to show error when user is in some textField
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 40),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Name is required";
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Enter your Name'),
                  ),
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Next"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {  // to check if the form is validate then navigate
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. Actually, I'm a beginner in flutter and I have another doubt so could you please help me with that too? It would be a great help.

Comment: where is the probleme ??

Comment: Can you please help me correct my code for this problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251155/a-renderflex-overflowed-by-99241-pixels-on-the-bottom-null-check-operator-used/68251619#68251619

Answer (score 0):

Add Form as the child of the Center Widget

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I'm a beginner in flutter and I have another doubt so could you please help me with that too? It would be a great help

Comment: sure what is that?

Comment: Hey, can you please help me with this problem?
Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412503/flutter-how-to-make-my-fields-required-and-save-my-dropdown-and-text-data-after