# Flutter: How to make my fields required and save my dropdown and text data after the submit button is pressed?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here is my code. I'm unable to save the responses and even the dropdown and the text fields are not showing the required text and the * sign with them. I can't get how can I save the responses submitted by the user and where to do it and what should I write on the on Pressed function in the submit button to save the responses of all the fields above it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
TextEditingController problemBox = TextEditingController();

List _listItem = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4"];
List _listItem1 = [
"Sub Category 1",
"Sub Category 2",
"Sub Category 3",
"Sub Category 4"
];
List _listItem2 = ["CRIS", "ADMINISTRATION", "ZONE", "DEPARTMENT"];

String dropdownValue;
String holder = '';

void getDropDownItem() {
setState(() {
  holder = dropdownValue;
});
}

String dropdownValue1;
String holder1 = '';

void getDropDownItem1() {
setState(() {
  holder1 = dropdownValue1;
});
}

String dropdownValue2;
String holder2 = '';

void getDropDownItem2() {
setState(() {
  holder2 = dropdownValue2;
});
}

bool autoValidate = true;
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Feedback"),
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
    ),
    body: Container(
        child: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("CATEGORY"),
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      items: _listItem
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem,
                          child: Text(valueItem),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("SUBCATEGORY"),
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      value: dropdownValue1,
                      items: _listItem1
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem1) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem1,
                          child: Text(valueItem1),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue1 = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("MARKED TO"),
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      value: dropdownValue2,
                      items: _listItem2
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem2) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem2,
                          child: Text(valueItem2),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue2 = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 00, 70, 00),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (String value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return "Name is required";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        controller: problemBox,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Describe your problem here.",
                        ),
                        maxLength: 1000,
                        maxLines: 5,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ButtonTheme(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _formKey.currentState.save();

                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    )));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the error of the textField check if the Form is validate :

```
 ButtonTheme(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("Submit"),
                            onPressed: () {
                             if(
                             _formKey.currentState.validate() // add this
                             ) {
                               print(" form is valideate"); // here do what you want when the form is validate :) 
                             }

                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
```

To validate dropDown , change DropdownButton to DropdownButtonFormField has a property validator –

```
  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(child: Text("MARKED TO")),
                        Flexible(
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>( // change to DropdownButtonFormField
                            hint: Text("Select"),
                            value: dropdownValue2,
     validator: (value) => value == null ? 'your message' : null,// add validator property
                            items: _listItem2
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem2) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: valueItem2,
                                child: Text(valueItem2),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownValue2 = value;
                              });
                            },
                   
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

and for * you can juste add it to required fields

Ex :

```
RichText(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'MARKED TO',
        
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: '*',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                    )
```

Comment: It worked thank you can you tell me how can I validate my dropdown values and make them mandatory and how can I print the * sign in the so that it look mandatory

Comment: For validate dropDown , change DropdownButton to DropdownButtonFormField has a property validator

Comment: Thanks, it worked great for me. Could you please help me with this question too?

Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468776/flutter-storing-data-on-same-collection-from-two-different-screen-in-firebase-a